# One-way sync from Linux to Flickr

Tags: linux, flickr

I am looking for a linux CLI alternative to [flickrsync](http://www.flickrsync.info/) for Windows.  I would like to sync a linux directory to flickr, with photos added, being automatically uploaded, and photos removed, being deleted from flickr.

Folders2Flickr only uploads, flickrfs does not seem to delete either and furthermore depends on app specific file permissions.

Comment: Probably better fits on [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @sebix I thought about that before posting, I checked with the cross-site search at stackexchange.com, and this site had all the related questions.  Thats why I posted it here (and it is basically a segment of a photo-workflow).

Comment: Haven't tried it, but take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/flickrsync/ It's written in perl, so it may run on Linux. The top descriptions don't say one way or the other.

Comment: Just downloaded it and it is in fact an exe == Windows. Tried to run it with mono runtime and wine with no success, so sorry for the earlier comment.

Comment: Found script source at http://sourceforge.net/p/flickrsync/code/ci/master/tree/backup2flickr.pl, but I don't know perl.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [folders2flickr](https://github.com/richq/folders2flickr/). It's a python script that has served me very well. As an added bonus, you can automatically add a label to the picture based on the foldername it is in.